# UDP SOCKET how to answer to a specific computer in the same network?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, client

Hello I am writing a server application with multiple clients.
For this i first authenticate the clients and the SOCKADDR_IN of the connected ones gets saved in an array.

Then i use the following to answer a specific client:

```
if(myArray[i].sin_addr.s_addr == current.sin_addr.s_s_addr)
```

This works because I am getting a LAN IP at the moment. Later when the server will not be in the same network and two clients from the same network connect I will get the same IP twice.
At least when i check the IP of mine and my brothers computer over one of the many sites that show the IP i see the same.

So how can i differentiate two computers in the same network from a remote server?

Comment: Your computers don't have the same IP address - the web sites are showing you the address of your broadband router. Before you go any further with this do some serious study on TCP/IP networking and get your ideas straight.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you could explain this situation to me: Two computers connected from the same network to the remote server are playing a game. One player gets a so called "IP-Ban" but both players can't connect anymore. I have seen this in Counter-Strike and TeamSpeak. That is where I originally got the idea. Can you maybe explain this to me or point me to some good ressources where I can read more about this?

Comment: Start with [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you are asking, each client would have to explicitly send to your server the local IP it is using to send packets to your server, then your server can store that extra IP along with the IP it receives on inbound packets from that client.  If the two IPs are different than you will know that the client is behind a router/NAT, and you will have to use both stored IPs as a pair to uniquely identify individual clients from the same network.  Your communication protocol will need a small handshake to establish that information.  For example:

```
C -> S: HELLO I want to talk to you
S: detects client's public IP:Port to send packets to

S -> C: WELCOME who are you
C: detects local IP that OS is using to route packets to/from the server

C -> S: IAMSAM here is my local IP
S: associates both public and private IPs with the client, allows further communication
```

If a client has the same public and private IPs then it is directly connected to the Internet.

If the public and private IPs are different than the client is behind a NAT:

1. If multiple clients are behind the same NAT then they will have the same public IP but different private IPs.
2. Clients on different NATs will have different public IPs but can have the same private IP.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I already thought of that just wanted to see if I can avoid sending an identifier with every package. But I am a little confused now since the other answer says that the IP's are not the same and I'm mistaken?

Comment: You are not mistaken. When two clients behind a NAT connect to the same server outside of the NAT, the server will see the same IP for both clients. You should not identify clients by IP alone, especially for this reason. Have each client login with a unique username, or have the server issue its own unique tokens, that have to be included in each packet (since you are using UDP instead of TCP).